# swig get return type from variable in struct as string array in java

Tags: java, c, arrays, string, swig

For a small Java project I needed to interact with existing code written in C, 
so to make things easy (I'm not a C/C++ programmer unfortunately..) I decided to use swig.

The first problem I encountered: 
a C function that returned a NULL-delimited string resulted in wrapped code that returned a String, containing only the first value
was solved by the 3(!) possible solutions Flexo provided in: [SWIG get returntype from String as String array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253529/swig-get-returntype-from-string-as-string-array-in-java)

While continuing development on this project I encountered a second problem with a (similar?) pattern that puzzles me:
The headerfile contains a struct "PROJECTDETAILS" that (in turn) contains a variable itemList that (should) contain a NULL-delimited String.
The swig generated getter for itemList returns the first result as a String, just like the GetProjects function in my original linked question
(a String containing the first result)
I've tried to apply the answer Flexo provided to this problem as wel, however I'm not able to "typemap" the itemList variable

The function in the C header file states:

```
typedef struct _PROJECT
{
    int version;
    unsigned char vM;
    unsigned char fM;
} * PROJECT;

typedef struct _PROJECTDETAILS
{
    int infoType;
    union
    {
        char *itemList;            /* Returns a NULL-delimited string */
        char *projectName;
    } info;
} PROJECTDETAILS;

DllImport PROJECT OpenProject dsproto((int, char *));
DllImport int GetProjectDetails dsproto((PROJECT, int, PROJECTDETAILS *));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start out I wrote a dummy implementation of what I assume the semantics of the two functions you referenced are:

```
typedef struct _PROJECT
{
    int version;
    unsigned char vM;
    unsigned char fM;
} * PROJECT;

#define INFOTYPE_ITEMLIST 0
#define INFOTYPE_PROJECTNAME 1

typedef struct _PROJECTDETAILS
{
    int infoType;
    union
    {
        char *itemList;            /* Returns a NULL-delimited string */
        char *projectName;
    } info;
} PROJECTDETAILS;

static PROJECT OpenProject(int a, char *b) {
    (void)a;(void)b;
    static struct _PROJECT p = {100, 1, 2};
    return &p;   
}

static int GetProjectDetails(PROJECT p, int a, PROJECTDETAILS *out) {
    (void)p;
    // No idea what real impl does here
    if (a == 1) {
      out->infoType = INFOTYPE_ITEMLIST; 
      out->info.itemList="Item 1\0Item 2\0Item 3\0";
    }
    else {
      out->infoType = INFOTYPE_PROJECTNAME;
      out->info.projectName = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This, combined with the answer I gave in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253529/swig-get-returntype-from-string-as-string-array-in-java) is sufficient to get the `itemList` member working, albeit in a clunky (for a Java developer's perspective) way.

To make use of the typemaps from the previous answer correctly all we need to do is figure out what to call them (or what to write for `%apply`). SWIG has a really handy way of helping us figure this out, the `-debug-tmsearch` command line argument that for every typemap search that happens prints all the candidates which are considered and ignored because nothing was entered for them. So I ran:

```
swig3.0 -java -Wall -debug-tmsearch test.i
```

Which then shows the ways we could match that with our typemaps from the previous answer.

```
test.h:16: Searching for a suitable 'out' typemap for: char *_PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList
  Looking for: char *_PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList
  Looking for: char *itemList
  Looking for: char *
  Using: %typemap(out) char *
```

Which shows that `char *_PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList` is the tightest match for the `PROJECTDETAILS::info::itemList` member that we want to apply our previous typemap to. So we could just use the previous typemaps in this answer and match differently (or even use `%apply` to match them to multiple usages), something like:

```c
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <assert.h>
%}

// See part 2 for discusson of these
%rename("%(strip:[_])s") "";
%immutable _PROJECTDETAILS::infoType;

%typemap(jni) char * _PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList "jobjectArray";
%typemap(jtype) char * _PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList "String[]";
%typemap(jstype) char * _PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList "String[]";
%typemap(javaout) char * _PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList {
  return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(out) char * _PROJECTDETAILS::_PROJECTDETAILS_info::itemList {
  size_t count = 0;
  const char *pos = $1;
  while (*pos) {
    while (*pos++); // SKIP
    ++count;
  }
  $result = JCALL3(NewObjectArray, jenv, count, JCALL1(FindClass, jenv, "java/lang/String"), NULL);
  pos = $1;
  size_t idx = 0;
  while (*pos) {
    jobject str = JCALL1(NewStringUTF, jenv, pos);
    assert(idx<count);
    JCALL3(SetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $result, idx++, str);
    while (*pos++); // SKIP
  }
  //free($1); // Iff you need to free the C function's return value
}

%include "test.h"
```

This picked method 2 from the previous answer, mainly because it was entirely typemap based, so a better example of the `-debug-tmsearch` SWIG argument.

That's enough that we can use it as:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    PROJECT p = test.OpenProject(1,"???");
    PROJECTDETAILS pd1 = new PROJECTDETAILS();
    test.GetProjectDetails(p, 1, pd1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pd1.getInfo().getItemList()));
  }
}
```

But we can do much better than that for Java users, creating a new `PROJECTDETAILS` object just to pass in as the argument to `GetProjectDetails` is a little odd.

---

To wrap this neatly into Java there are quite a few things you want to do, besides just the member variable with unusual semantics for `char *`.

First up we probably want to rename some of the structs you've got. You can do that in SWIG 2.0 and above using the advanced renaming strip operator.

Next we need to decide how to wrap the members themselves. A typical design pattern in C is to use an int to indicate which member of a union is the correct type for a given object. In Python I'd just return a different type for each case and rely on duck-typing. For Java there are a couple of different options that would be sensible:

1. You could define a class hierarchy and use `instanceof` (or just the int type) to figure out how to cast to the right type.
2. You could leave it as is and mirror the C semantics. (Technically accessing the 'wrong' member is undefined behaviour, which isn't very intuitive for Java developers).
3. You could return a type that raise an exception or return NULL instead if you try to access the 'wrong' member.

Option 2 is what the previous part of this answer did. From my perspective option 3 is probably the most predictable behaviour to a Java programmer, so that's what I've done here.

The third fun decision we need to make is how to handle the output function argument. In this instance I'm going to pick the solution that favours more Java code over more C/JNI, but the same trade off as with previous answers applies here too.

So what I did is to tell SWIG to ignore `PROJECTDETAILS::info` completely, as well as renaming the underscore prefixed structs.

Then I made the version of `GetProjectDetails` in the header file private and added the `Impl` suffix to show that it's not intended for anyone other than internals of the wrapper to touch it.

Inside the module itself I used `%pragma` to add another, public version of `GetProjectDetails` that hides the fact that a new object is constructed for an output only argument, changes the return type to return this. It also switches the 'use `int` to indicate success' C coding style into the Java 'throw an exception if it goes wrong' mechanism. (There are more ways in SWIG to do this than just like this, but it minimizes the C/JNI learning curve to do it like that).

Then we add two extra, read-only member variables to the wrapped `PROJECTDETAILS` struct. These don't really exist in C directly, so they're implemented in the intermediate interface glue code by some extra C code. The point of this code is that it checks what case the `union` is actually in, using the extra `int` member that indicates the type. If the type isn't right they return null (but either C or Java glue code could make that an exception instead).

All we have to do with that is then re-use the typemaps from my previous answer to get the `itemList` semantics working right across the language boundary. Again I used method 2 here, other than the minor issue with functions returning null it's unchanged.

```c
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <assert.h>
%}

%rename("%(strip:[_])s") "";
%immutable _PROJECTDETAILS::infoType;
%ignore info; // Ignore the member
%ignore _PROJECTDETAILS_info; // Ignore the anonymous type
%javamethodmodifiers GetProjectDetails "private";
%rename(GetProjectDetailsImpl) GetProjectDetails;

%typemap(jni) char *_PROJECTDETAILS::itemList "jobjectArray";
%typemap(jtype) char *_PROJECTDETAILS::itemList "String[]";
%typemap(jstype) char *_PROJECTDETAILS::itemList "String[]";
%typemap(javaout) char *_PROJECTDETAILS::itemList {
  return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(out) char *_PROJECTDETAILS::itemList {
  if (!$1) return NULL; // This fixes a possible bug in my previous answer
  size_t count = 0;
  const char *pos = $1;
  while (*pos) {
    while (*pos++); // SKIP
    ++count;
  }
  $result = JCALL3(NewObjectArray, jenv, count, JCALL1(FindClass, jenv, "java/lang/String"), NULL);
  pos = $1;
  size_t idx = 0;
  while (*pos) {
    jobject str = JCALL1(NewStringUTF, jenv, pos);
    assert(idx<count);
    JCALL3(SetObjectArrayElement, jenv, $result, idx++, str);
    while (*pos++); // SKIP
  }
  //free($1); // Iff you need to free the C function return value
}

%pragma(java) modulecode=%{
  public static PROJECTDETAILS GetProjectDetails(PROJECT p, int a) {
    PROJECTDETAILS out = new PROJECTDETAILS();
    final int ret = GetProjectDetailsImpl(p,a,out);
    if (0!=ret) {
      // assuming this is an error throw something
    }
    return out;
  }
%}

%extend _PROJECTDETAILS {
  const char *itemList const {
    if ($self->infoType != INFOTYPE_ITEMLIST) {
     // Throw a Java exception here instead? That is another question...
     return NULL;
    }
    return $self->info.itemList;
  }
  const char *projectName const {
    if ($self->infoType != INFOTYPE_PROJECTNAME) {
      // Throw exception?
      return NULL;
    }
    return $self->info.projectName;
  }
}

%include "test.h"
```

Which then works with:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    PROJECT p = test.OpenProject(1,"???");

    System.out.println("PD1");
    PROJECTDETAILS pd1 = test.GetProjectDetails(p, 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pd1.getItemList()));
    System.out.println(pd1.getProjectName());

    System.out.println("PD2");
    PROJECTDETAILS pd2 = test.GetProjectDetails(p, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pd2.getItemList()));
    System.out.println(pd2.getProjectName());
  }
}
```

(Note: anything that starts with _ followed by a capital letter is a [reserved name](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html), probably not your fault, but not exactly great C)

Comment: my apologies for the late reply! I've tried both of the suggested implementations and they work perfectly!
I must say that I really appreciate the clear and extensive explanations you provided, it really helps me to get a better understanding of whats actually happening (instead of just crossing my fingers and hoping the best from a "copy/paste") ;)

Comment: Just wondering, another function in the header file takes the PROJECTDETAILS structure as an input parameter, the SWIG generated code allows me to set the infoType of the PROJECTDETAILS, however I cant set the value of a variable associated with the infoType, for instance the projectName. Im guessing this would require an additional %typemap

Comment: @c3po if you remove `%immutable` for it you can set it, but if you need to do anything clever like free the existing values it'll take more work.

Comment: I seem to be doing something wrong. When I remove    %immutable the resulting code (in PROJECTDETAILS) doesn't include setters for the variable projectName, just the setInfoType. The PROJECTDETAILS_info class does contain setters. I'm probably wrong but I don't think that casting would work here?

Comment: @c3po I see now. I think you'll need to write set/get methods similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11340461/168175 in that case for the `%extend`.

Comment: seems that I misunderstood the getInfo() method... works perfectly now! thanks!